# TensorRT Object Detection with TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorrt

I have written the following code to optimize a TensorFlow 1 object detection model with TensorRT and then run inference on a Jetson Nano. However, it runs the inference but returns `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar` index without displaying the identified objects on the image.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import urllib
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
from tf_trt_models.detection import download_detection_model, build_detection_graph

%matplotlib inline

config_path = '/home/dev/Downloads/SSD_MobileNet_300000/pipeline.config'
checkpoint_path = '/home/dev/Downloads/SSD_MobileNet_300000/model.ckpt'

DATA_DIR = '/home/dev/Downloads'

frozen_graph, input_names, output_names = build_detection_graph(
    config=config_path,
    checkpoint=checkpoint_path,
    score_threshold=0.1,
    batch_size=1
)

print(output_names)

trt_graph = trt.create_inference_graph(
    input_graph_def=frozen_graph,
    outputs=output_names,
    max_batch_size=1,
    max_workspace_size_bytes=1 << 25,
    precision_mode='FP16',
    minimum_segment_size=50
)

with open('/home/dev/Downloads/SSD_MobileNet_300000/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(trt_graph.SerializeToString())

tf_config = tf.ConfigProto()
tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

tf_sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)

tf.import_graph_def(trt_graph, name='')

tf_input = tf_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_names[0] + ':0')
tf_scores = tf_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
tf_boxes = tf_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
tf_classes = tf_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
tf_num_detections = tf_sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

image = Image.open('/home/dev/Downloads/test/P2794.png')

plt.imshow(image)

image_resized = np.array(image.resize((320, 320)))
image = np.array(image)

scores, boxes, classes, num_detections = tf_sess.run([tf_scores, tf_boxes, tf_classes, tf_num_detections], feed_dict={
    tf_input: image_resized[None, ...]
})

boxes = boxes[0] # index by 0 to remove batch dimension
scores = scores[0]
classes = classes[0]
num_detections = num_detections[0]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(image)

# plot boxes exceeding score threshold
for i in range(num_detections):
    # scale box to image coordinates
    box = boxes[i] * np.array([image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[0], image.shape[1]])

    # display rectangle
    patch = patches.Rectangle((box[1], box[0]), box[3] - box[1], box[2] - box[0], color='g', alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_patch(patch)

    # display class index and score
    plt.text(x=box[1] + 10, y=box[2] - 10, s='%d (%0.2f) ' % (classes[i], scores[i]), color='w')

plt.show()

num_samples = 1

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(num_samples):
    scores, boxes, classes, num_detections = tf_sess.run([tf_scores, tf_boxes, tf_classes, tf_num_detections], feed_dict={
        tf_input: image_resized[None, ...]
    })
t1 = time.time()
print('Average runtime: %f seconds' % (float(t1 - t0) / num_samples))
```

Here is a snippet of the error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing `num_detection = num_detections[0]` to `num_detection = int(num_detections[0])`